# Gridview.Databind() not refresh the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

First of all, sorry if I make mistakes in english...

I'm making a web with c#, and I have some problems for refresh the data displayed in the GridView

I'm getting the data throw the SqlDataSource defined at the aspx view:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXX %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX.ProviderName %>" DataSourceMode="DataSet" SelectCommand=" select EAN, CODART.....  "> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I click a button, I update some data in the database, and I want refresh de GridView with the new data, without reload the page.
I'm making: `gridView.DataBind();`, but that doesn't refresh the data in the GridView.

(At the database is updated)

The `GridView` is inside of an `UpdatePanel`.

I was trying some things, like:

- Reassing the `DataSourceID`  and make the `gridView.DataBind();`
- Assing the `DataSourceID` in `null`, make the `gridView.DataBind();`, and alter reassing the `DataSourceID` and make the `gridView.DataBind();`
- I tried too:

```
    DataSourceSelectArguments argumentos = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    
    PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK.Select(argumentos);
    
    gridView.DataBind();
```

- Set the `UpdatePanel` to `updatemode="Always"`

But any of all of that worked...
Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: where are you actually setting the data source, should be something like: gridView.DataSource = DataSourceHere;  then you call the databind.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that: ` eanList.DataSource = PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK;
eanList.DataBind();` but the data still not reloading, although in the BD the data is updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue.

In my case, I was calling in the front, in `AJAX`, the C# method, that method is an `WebMethod` `HttpPost`

The issue was that I was saving in a `Session` the `GridView` and the `SqlDataSource`, and although I was executing the Select statement again, I was obtaining the old's values.

I was saving in a `Session` that information because the `AJAX` execute the method direct and the `GridView` and the `SqlDataSource` were `null`

Finally I tried to make a refresh from the `GridVeiw` by a button, and the info is updated correctly, so, I hided the button, and simulate the `click` button in `AJAX`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pageUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ gridMod: gridMod }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            document.getElementById("<%= btnReload.ClientID %>").click();
        },
    });
```

So, the click event call to `LoadGrid();`, and this one execute:

```
private void LoadGrid()
    {

        DataSourceSelectArguments argumentos = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

        PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK.Select(argumentos);


        eanList.DataBind();


    }
```

In this way, I can refresh the data "automatically" without clicking in any button

Answer (score 0):

Why not dump the datasource setting on the page of PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK.

I find that when you need to filtere, load, and play?

Just remove the data source from the markup. So, in your GridView, remove the data source id setting of PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK, and then delete the data source.

You have to write a BIT more code, but you now have control over the data, and MORE important, control over which parameters you need and want.

So, say I have this markup:

A grid, and also a search/text box to filter the grid.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search for Fighter jet" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Style="margin-left:15px" Font-Size="Large">
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="search"
    style="margin-left:15px" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />

<br />
<br />

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px"
                    OnClientClick ="popimage(this);return false"
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' /> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Note close - I did build this grid using the wizards. But I THEN removed the Datasource ID for the GV, and removed the Datasource that was created in the markup.

So, now my code to load is this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid("");
    }

    void LoadGrid(string MySearch)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters ", conn))
            {
                if (MySearch != "")
                {
                    cmdSQL.CommandText += @" WHERE Fighter LIKE @Fighter + '%'";
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("Fighter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MySearch;
                }
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I get this:

[image]

And note the "optional" filter for the text box. If you type in some text, (I used a "like" match in sql), then the code is only this:

```
    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(txtSearch.Text);
    }
```

but, the idea here is often it is much better to dump the SqlDataSoruce placed in the markup, and roll + write your own code. The problem is you can try and set the data source in code, but ALSO WITH a data source on the page - they fight over each other. So, try the above idea - and remove the data source in the markup.

Comment: I tried that, I set de gridview.DataSourceID = ""; and all the sql select statement, return the DataSet, and assing the `gridview.DataSource = dataSet` and later the `gridView.DataBind();`, but I still having the problem that the data is not the new one